# Bettert way than nested SELECT statements SQL

Tags: php, sql

I want to update the products in a cart table. If the user choose an option, the product id will change to the one with the desired option (each products are included in the products table with a different id by variant).

I made a nested request to select the product the user whant to change from the cart table, then find it in the product table, get the reference code, then find the siblings with the same reference code, and keep the good one with the desired variant. Finally, I update the cart table.

Is there a better way to do that? If yes, it will be faster or safer, or just easier to read?

Thank you.

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_product
   WHERE code=(SELECT code FROM tbl_product
    WHERE id=(SELECT product_id FROM tbl_cart
      WHERE id='".$_POST['cartId']."' AND member_id=$memberId))
        AND option_1='".$_POST['option']."'");
$product = $result->fetch_assoc();


$query = "UPDATE tbl_cart SET product_id = ?, quantity = ? WHERE id = ? AND member_id = ?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('iiii', $product['id'], $_POST["newQuantity"], $_POST["cartId"], $memberId);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

The table product:

```
+----+------------+--------+----------+--------+
| id |    name    |  code  | option_1 | price  |
+----+------------+--------+----------+--------+
|  2 | Hard Drive | USB2   |          | 199.90 |
|  3 | Watch      | Wear   |          | 150.50 |
|  6 | Camera     | 3DcA   | L        | 109.99 |
|  7 | Camera     | 3DcA   | XL       | 119.99 |
|  8 | Camera     | 3DcA   | XXL      | 129.99 |
|  9 | Camera     | 3DcA   | M        |  99.99 |
+----+------------+--------+----------+--------+
```

The table cart:

```
+-----+------------+----------+-----------+
| id  | product_id | quantity | member_id |
+-----+------------+----------+-----------+
| 176 |          6 |        1 |         1 |
+-----+------------+----------+-----------+
```

I added the two tables, to show you how they are made.
Maybe I have made a mistake on the way I built them.
Is this the good way to create parent/child structure?

Comment: The `SET product_id = ?` in update query seems redundant as you are updating the foreign key, *product_id* to same value used in *tbl_cart* and *tbl_product* subquery correlation in `SELECT`.

Comment: I need to search over all the products with the same code in the table product to find the one with the goo option. That's why I do a SELECT 2 times on the table_product.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, that query is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should be using prepared statements for your `SELECT` in the same way that you are using them for your `UPDATE`.

From an execution standpoint, it is likely that your SQL engine is optimizing this query using [Semi-Joins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/semi-joins.html). That link explains how semi-join optimization works in MySQL. Because of that you ***probably*** aren't taking a performance hit.

It also looks like your first subquery is redundant, if `product_id` is already in `tbl_products` why do you need to do a subquery for a `code` in the same table?

That said, from a readability standpoint I would use `JOIN`s from the beginning. Without seeing your schema, I can't be 100% sure but something like this is probably close to the Join version of the query.

```
$query = "SELECT products.* FROM tbl_cart cart
    JOIN tbl_product products ON products.id = cart.product_id
    WHERE cart.id = ?
    AND cart.member_id = ?
    AND products.option_1 = ?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param($_POST['cartId'], $memberId, $_POST['option']);
$stmt->execute();
$product = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
```

Note that the above assumes MySQL or MariaDB.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your `UPDATE`? I thought your question was about your nested sub-queries?

Comment: The code work well, I just want to know if I can do it better.

Answer (score 0):

Consider MySQL's `UPDATE...JOIN` syntax and avoid the first `SELECT` query call. Below removes the redundant *product_id* assignment. Also, *option_1* is handled in `JOIN` clause and is assumed to be a string value.

```
$query = "UPDATE tbl_cart c
          INNER JOIN tbl_product p
          SET c.product_id = p.id,
              c.quantity = ?,
          WHERE c.id = ? 
            AND c.member_id = ?
            AND p.option_1 = ?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('iiis', $_POST["newQuantity"], $_POST["cartId"], 
                          $memberId, $_POST['option']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

[Db Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tSAru8MnmWALCVKDNSGfLm/2)

Comment: I don't undertand this line: JOIN tbl_product p ON c.product_id = p.id AND option_1 = ?  How it can select the good option_1 if it select only the the product where : c.product_id = p.id ?

Comment: Hmmmm...this fiddle (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tSAru8MnmWALCVKDNSGfLm/0) using your posted data does update the *quantity* from 1 to 55 if the appropriate parameters are passed through ('L', 55, 176, 1 -respectively). Since demo does not support PHP, params are in MySQL. Be sure to click **Run** at top to see and scroll through all bottom results.

Comment: The problem is not the quantity, since the quantity is just updated on the same product_id. The problem is the variable option. If ou change for example 'L' to 'XL', the product_id should change from 6 to 7. But nothing happens.

Comment: See updated and demo link. You want a cross join or join without any `ON`.

Comment: Thank you, this one work well. Can you explain me what is the difference between the two? And what it does exactly? Also, I want to test my code and yours to compare the performances, how can I do it?

Comment: There is a bug with your code, when I change a product without options, it change the id of the product, i mean the product itself.

Comment: This solution depends specifically on options to narrow the join to specific row match. Do not run without them. The difference should be clear in that we are running one action query across multiple tables (not two with PHP fetching needed values) and only making one call to database.