# Updating products stocks in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to update the stock quantities of my products in the DB after a purchase.

My code already works fine, but I want to know if there is a best way to do, with only one SQL statement?

```
// All the product in the member's cart
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT product_id, quantity FROM tbl_cart WHERE member_id = ?")) {
  $stmt->bind_param("i", $memberId);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->get_result();
  $stmt->close();
  $cartItem = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Set the quantity after purchase
  foreach ($cartItem as $key => $item) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE tbl_product SET stock = stock-? WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $item['quantity'], $item['product_id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be worth looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query which shows how to do an `UPDATE... SELECT...`

Comment: I don't see how or why you would do it with 1 sql statement. Your stock and id parameters change for each cart item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the solution I found. I think it's just more clean.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE tbl_product AS p 
                        JOIN tbl_cart AS c
                        ON p.id = c.product_id 
                        SET p.stock = p.stock-c.quantity
                        WHERE c.member_id = ?");
  $stmt->bind_param("i", $memberId);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is nearly the same as my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56972860/1422451) on your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is better way but you may try this Sql statement.

```
UPDATE tbl_product 
SET stock = stock - ( SELECT quantity FROM tbl_cart 
WHERE product_id = tbl_product.id AND member_id = ? ) 
WHERE id IN ( SELECT product_id FROM tbl_cart WHERE member_id = ? )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using trigger function. Look here: [mysql after insert trigger which updates another table's column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892070/mysql-after-insert-trigger-which-updates-another-tables-column)

You could update other column when order is placed.

In my opinion, the trigger function is not the best option, because it will move logic to other place.

But it is one of the alternative, that you ask for.